# How to make the UISplit view controller works similar to iPhone for iPad destination?Is there any issue with segues?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

In My app,I used split view controller, it works fine in iPhone,but not in iPad destination.It may be functionality or UI bug
.I couldn't find out.I post the screen shots below for reference.

I tried out this in demo project same issue occurs.

1.This Image shows the iPhone destination's(simulator mode) "view controller" of the split view controller.

[image]

2.This Image shows the iPhone's "Root view controller", when I click back button in "view controller"  it goes to "Root view controller".

[image]

3.Again If I click the apply button,it shows the "view controller".This Image shows this.
[image]

Up to this It works fine in iPhone.

4.This image shows the iPad "view controller" of the split view controller.

[image]

5.when I scroll the view controller horizontally it shows the "root view controller".

[image]

Up to this it works fine in iPad.

6.If I click the apply button of the "Root view controller" it shows "view  controller" in "master view" not in "detail view".This screen shot shows this.

[image]

I solved the above issue using below story board and code.

7.This is my story board image.I had tried like this.But it having some issues.

[image].

For this story board I put this code:

```
- (IBAction)btnApply:(id)sender 
{
ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"wktimefilter"];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:Nil];
}
```

This is my next issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795396/split-view-controller-issue-with-iphone-and-ipad-tab-bar-disappears-moving-from

For this my Story board like this:

1.splitview controller ---> navigation controller ---> Root view controller ---> view controller

2.Again view controller connected with split view controller.

My Piece of code for onclick the apply button:

```
// when I click apply button in "Root view controller" moves to "view controller" 

- (IBAction)btnApply:(id)sender 
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"view controller" sender:sender];
}
```

In storyboard segue between "root view controller" and  "view controller".

In attributes  inspector

segue:push
destination:current

Destination having some other options it is given by:

1.master split.
2.detail split.

If I changed segue to : "Replace"  destination:"detail split".It throws error.

Now I tried to embed navigation controller for view controller.then connect a segue between "Root view controller" and "navigation controller".But it doesn't works.How to solve this?

How to fix this issue in iPad?Through UI or code. Is there any possibilities to avoid this.Any suggestions,Thanks in Advance.

Sorry For confusing one question with other,Right now the issue is the next question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795396/split-view-controller-issue-with-iphone-and-ipad-tab-bar-disappears-moving-from

Comment: Now I edited the question and asked the issue correctly.Please suggest me ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Show Detail segue. If you're already doing that, there may be something wrong with your master detail setup. Is this how your storyboard is configured?
[image]

Comment: bro it shows push,modal,custom as options.And one more thing how to convert the story board in to image.if you help this out .I  will post the story board bro...

Comment: It's the root view controller because of this it shows push,modal, custom as its options.

Comment: By image, I mean a screenshot.

Comment: yeah i am also asking similar bro....how to make the screen shot of story board.really i don't know bro...how to do this..

Comment: Press Command + Shift + 3. The screenshot will be created on the desktop.

Comment: without copying the story board....i am using windows keyboard...so i press ctrl+shift+3 ...nothing created in desktop bro....

Comment: similar story board instead of connecting root view controller with the navigation controller, i connected directly root view controller with view controller...is there any problem bro....because of this..

Comment: Yes, that is what's causing the problem. The detail view needs its own navigation stack.

Comment: what might be the solution bro...i have to embed in navigation controller for view controller..just now i tried this....but it throws error.....after embed in navigation controller for view controller i have code something or else what i have to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105148/discussion-between-themobileapper-and-jsaonboo).

Comment: bro one more thing in your story board screen shot in attributes inspector it shows segue  and destination  but in your screen shot it shows class,module...your Xcode is 7.2 ...because mine is 6.4 only..

Comment: bro i  have some tab bar items in split view controller when i use navigation controller if i connect directly segue between navigation and root view controller it throws error.so i put this code..- (IBAction)btnApply:(id)sender {
  //fixed issue for split view controller in ipad
   WktimeListViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"wktimefilter"];
   [self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:Nil];
    }   then the tab bar shows in navigation controller not in next controller.